# Keydown event vb.net fails to respond?

Tags: vb.net, keydown

I have the following code snipet which I have in my vb.net program but it dosnt work???
it has absolutly no response, perhaps someoneout there knows why?

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Q AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + Q Pressed !")
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm using VB.net

Comment: Do you have the KeyPreview property of the form set to true?

Comment: you try in key press event

Answer (score 0):

Set `KeyPreview`property of the form to true.  The form will then get to know about key events even when a control has focus.

Comment: KeyPreview is a VB6 compat property and should be avoided.  It works in this case but it tends to disappoint since the VB6 behavior is quirky, only certain keystrokes are passed to KeyDown.  The universal solution is to override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method instead.